# with jquery how can i expose a single DOM element that is lower on the DOM tree?

Tags: jquery, css

i want to target a single DOM element, and expose it by keeping it visible while having an overlay cover everything else on the screen.

just like jQuery.expose() does http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/toolbox/expose.html

the problem with the above is that it doesn't work if the element is a child that's lower on the DOM tree.  i.e. if element Y is at the top level, and element X is a child of Y, then calling X.expose() creates an overlay div that is z-indexed over Y.  X's z-index is set to 9998 but it's a child of Y so it sits below the overlay div.

alternative solutions very welcome.  i had considered doing a .clone() and then appendTo('body'), then using offset() to position the clone, but .clone() doesnt' always produce an exact copy due to inherited css properties.

Comment: Can you post some code or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It will be easier to help that way. Also you *are* using jQuery.expose or not?

Comment: sorry but i tried a really simple example with jquery.expose() on jsfiddle and the overlay was really messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Don't append the target DOM element inside your overlay, you won't get the desired effect that you want.

What you can do is append the target DOM element and overlay to the same container (ex. body)...

```
$('#my-target').appendTo($('body'));
```

...then you can also do the same with your overlay...

```
$('#my-overlay').appendTo($('body'));
```

...then you can adjust both element's z-index...

```
$('#my-target').css('z-index', 9999);
$('#my-overlay').css('z-index', 9998);
```

... alternatively, you can do all of the above with...

```
$('#my-target').appendTo($('body')).css('z-index', 9999);
$('#my-overlay').appendTo($('body')).css('z-index', 9998);
```

Comment: i have edited my response, i did in fact appendTo body, not to the overlay, that was a mistake.  the problem with this approach is that .clone() is not guaranteed to create a perfect clone of the target element.  in my experience sizing was different, i think due to inherited css properties.

Comment: Well, then don't clone/append your target element, only append the overlay to another container, keep it where it is (as long as it is not inside the overlay) then just change its z-index

Answer (score 0):

the answer was dead simple - all i had to do was clone() an element into the hierarchy of the source element so that the css properties are also inherited and the size/style of the clone is identical.

then set the cloned element to position: absolute and z-index to one above the overlay div.

setting position absolute makes that element's z-index global, independent of the DOM hierarchy.